# Visual Studio 2019 inspections for NullableContextOptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm using the latest VS 2019 Preview, but not getting any inspections or IDE errors/warnings with NullableContextOptions enabled in csproj.

I do get the compiler warnings when building, but no visual warnings in the IDE Editor.  I would have thought they would have support for this, is there something that has to be done to turn on the inspections?

My csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp</RootNamespace>
        <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
        <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Stupid question, have you closed and reopened the solution and VS? Also try unloading the project and then reloading... It was a reported issue [please](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9517#issuecomment-446389576) see there about it.

Comment: Now that VS 2019 is actually out, it looks like they've changed things.  With VS2019, it works, but requires LangVersion to be preview.

Comment: yes who knows with MS... ;) I found that earlier doing a simple search, evidentially it was an issue, but was fixed in the release...

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of on me for trying to use an unsupported language version, but the project won't be done for a few months and I could see a lot of benefits out of nullable reference type checks.

Comment: yeah definitely for sure, avoiding those common mistakes will save leading to other issues down the road with all the help of this new check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that VS 2019 has been released, this feature works but it required me to use "preview" instead of "8.0" as the LangVersion.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 16.2 the property name was changed to `Nullable`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```